# simulate/emulate hover in/out on another element by hovering a different element - jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to simulate a hover using jquery but on another element.

Basically I have my slideshow below...

```
<div id="slideshow">

...

</div>
```

And I have these setting on...

```
var slider = $('#slideshow').bxSlider({
    autoHover: true 
})
```

These setting simply make the slideshow pause when the `<div id="slideshow">` is hovered. The slideshow begins to play when you roll out.

My question is, is there anyway to simulate the hover action on `<div id="slideshow">`, but instead when this element below is hovered in/out?

```
<div id="slideshow-custom-nav">

... // When this element is hovered in/out, I need it to pause/continue the slideshow. So by simulating a hover on the #slideshow div, this should work hopefully.

</div>
```

Any suggestions would be most awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, yes. You'd have to trigger an hover event manually using jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method.

I haven't used bxSlider myself, but I believe you'd have to find if the plugin is triggering a custom event so you can specify that event when calling `.trigger()`

**Update**

Ok, after a quick look at the bxSlider code on GitHub, I saw that it uses normal events throughout the plugin code. As you can see at [line 770](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js#L770), the plugin is defining the handlers for both the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events for the element `el` (which is defined at [line 90](https://github.com/wandoledzep/bxslider-4/blob/master/jquery.bxslider.js#L90)).

So, as an educated guess, you might try to trigger those events yourself, where you see fit. Something like:

```
$('#slideshow-custom-nav').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('#slideshow').trigger('mouseenter');
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $('#slideshow').trigger('mouseleave');
});
```

Comment: Thank you will check it out now

Comment: Nope. I couldn't find the custom event in the plugin to trigger. I'm sure there is one but I'm not sure what I'm looking for :/